# importlib.reload() not realoading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I am trying to create a leetcode like online judge. I need to reload the submission module but `import.reload()` does not work.

### The code:

```
class Test:
    current_exercise = None
    current_name = None

    def _import(self, exercise):
        exercise = 'exercise'    # for testing 

        if exercise == self.current_name:
            module = sys.modules[f'puzzles.{exercise}']
            self.current_exercise = importlib.reload(module)    # <---- not working 
        else:
            self.current_name = exercise
            self.current_exercise = __import__(f'puzzles.{exercise}').exercise

    def _test(self, exercise):
        solution = self._import(exercise)
        print(self.current_exercise.main())

if __name__=='__main__':
    import shutil
    t= Test()

    # first run 
    t._test('exercise')
    
    # copy another solution.py for reload test
    shutil.copy(f"./puzzles/other_exercise/solution.py", f"./puzzles/exercise/solution.py")

    # second run 
    t._test('exercise')
```

### My directory;

```
.
├── codetest.py
├── puzzles
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── exercise
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── solution.py
│   ├── other_exercise
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── solution.py
```

### exercise/solution.py:

```
def main(): 
    print('EXERCISE')
```

### exercise/**init**.py

```
from .solution import main
from .test import cases
```

### other_exercise/solution.py:

```
def main(): 
    print('OTHER EXERCISE')
```

### Output:

```
> EXERCISE
> EXERCISE   # <--- not sucessfull, should be 'OTHER EXERCISE'
```

Comment: What is the `.p0` doing at the end of your `__import__` line?

Comment: It doesn't work any other way.

Comment: Interesting.  What's in your `__init__.py` files?  `main()` won't be available unless someone imported `solution`.

Comment: You are right, I updated my question.

Comment: I just don't understand the need for `.exercise` in your `__import__` line.  It doesn't make sense.  If you skip that and `print(self.current_exercise)` after that, what do you see?

Comment: ```print(self.current_exercise.main())
AttributeError: module 'puzzles' has no attribute 'main'
'``` and by removing ```{exercise}```: ```self.current_exercise = __import__(f'puzzles').exercise
AttributeError: module 'puzzles' has no attribute 'exercise'```

Comment: One helpful hint: you should replace the unrecommended `__import__` with `importlib.import_module(f"puzzles.{exercise}")`.  It doesn't solve the root problem, but it does eliminate the need for the extra `.exercise` suffix.

Comment: Thank you but I went with an alternative. I'm not sure if it's efficient but the code is rather simple.

Comment: The issue seems to be that reimporting "puzzles/exercise" does nothing to reimport solutions.py.  If you change your reimport line to  `self.current_exercise.solution = importlib.reload(self.current_exercise.solution)` then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
import sys
import time
import importlib

class Test:
    current_exercise = None
    current_name = None

    def _import(self, exercise):

        if exercise == self.current_name:
            self.current_exercise.solution = importlib.reload(self.current_exercise.solution)
        else:
            self.current_name = exercise
            self.current_exercise = importlib.import_module(f'puzzles.{exercise}')
        print('mod',self.current_exercise)
        print('nam',self.current_exercise.__name__)
        print('fil',self.current_exercise.__file__)
        print('pkg',self.current_exercise.__package__)

    def _test(self, exercise):
        solution = self._import(exercise)
        print(self.current_exercise.solution.main())

if __name__=='__main__':
    import shutil
    shutil.copy(f"./puzzles/exercise/solution.0", f"./puzzles/exercise/solution.py")
    t= Test()

    # first run 
    t._test('exercise')
    
    # copy another solution.py for reload test
    shutil.copy("./puzzles/other_exercise/solution.py", "./puzzles/exercise/solution.py")
    print(open("./puzzles/exercise/solution.py").read())

    # second run 
    t._test('exercise')
```

Comment: Benchmarking with ```time.perf_counter()```,  loading the file and than loading the code with```imp``` is faster: 0.0005 vs 0.0030. The code is cleaner but ```imp``` is deprecated and I haven't benchmarked for multiple runs of the same module. if statements are expensive.

Comment: The timing of this is irrelevant.  This is something that will only get run on demand with a new submission.

Answer (score 0):

I went with an alternative; load `solution.py` as a text and create a module from that string. The module is not registered in `sys.modules` and can be overwritten. However `imp` is deprecated.

```
import imp

class Test:
    current_exercise = None

    def _import(self, exercise):

        # load module code 
        with open(f'./puzzles/{exercise}/solution.py') as f:
            code = f.read()

            # register/create the module
            self.current_exercise = imp.new_module('mymodule')

            # import/fill the module 
            exec(code, self.current_exercise.__dict__)

    def _test(self, exercise):
        self._import(exercise)
        print(self.current_exercise.main())
```